# cases where new height is not applied. I can't see it

Tags: javascript, css

**tl;dr** - 
The issue was caused by the 5px padding on the topbar. @RyanKinal Thanks for noticing that!

---

This issue is dealing with a userscript i'm authoring (forked from someone else).

The script pulls the userlist out of the chat and displays it in a nice little auto-hide bar at the top of your page.

The full script is long and I don't want to pollute the page - you can see it [here](https://github.com/rlemon/UserScripts/blob/master/Upbar/bar.user.js)

My issue is that in certain cases ( I can't figure out what they are ) the height of the new topbar is not calculated properly.

*setting the height*

```
var setHeight = function() {
    _top = -(topbar.height() - 15);
    topbar.css('top', (stuck ? 0 : _top));
};
```

and the real meat and potatoes of the script.

```
    topbar.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'left': '0px',
        'z-index': '1',
        'width': '49%',
        'background-color': '#fff',
        'border-bottom': '2px solid #777',
        'box-shadow': '0px 5px 10px #777',
        'padding': '5px'
    });
topbar.append( $(document.getElementById('present-users')).detach() );
topbar.append( menu.detach() );
chat_body.append(topbar);
    setHeight();
    this.onresize = function() {
        if( !stuck ) {
            setHeight();
        }
    };
    this.onresize();

    topbar.hover(function() {
        if( !stuck ) {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({top:0}, 300, function() {
                checkHidden();
            });
        }

    }, function() {
        if( !stuck ) {
            $(this).stop(false, false).animate({top:_top}, 300);
            checkTop();
        }
    });
```

What *should be happening* is the topbar pulls the applicable containers from the sidebar - calculates their height - then sets up the correct 'top' css rule on the element.

I can't give you steps to reproduce only images. (I THINK it only happens when there is a single user overflow in the userlist)

*Should look*
[image: This is how it should look first load.]

*under certain circumstances this is how it does look*
[image: This is how it actually looks first load.]

The script still opens and closes, but with the 'broken' top value.
[image: This is how it actually looks open]

So once it is broken, mouseout takes it back to the second image there.

**UPDATE**

I have confirmed it only happens when a single user wraps to a new line - 
Steps to reproduce: 
1) Install the script 
2) open the chat.se or chat.so chat room
3) for ease, make the topbar 'stick' open
4) resize the browser window so only one user wraps to a new line
5) unstick the topbar
6) refresh the page

Comment: QUESTION 1: Do you know for sure what the value of the cookie (stuck) is when the height doesn't work properly?

Comment: the cookie only stores whether or not the sticky is applied. and yes it is retained.

Comment: QUESTION 2: I've looked at the linked JavaScript code page, but I haven't seen any place where the min-height gets set for the topbar DIV. That would solve part of your problem. The other issue I would address (for cross-browser compatibility) is to add either a class or an ID of topbar to the DIV that's getting dynamically created. And then adjust the CSS to either .topbar (class) or #topbar (ID).

Comment: thats not a concern right now. min-height isn't the problem either.. if you read my issue and look at the code you will see the setHeight() function works... it is not getting the correct values on load in *some* cases... i really do think it's only when there is that one extra user.. maybe a box issue?

Comment: The confusing bit is that the height is never set. The `setHeight` function depends on the height of the `present-users` list, but does not set it.

Comment: yes that is correct. the function name is confusing. it sets the position top biased on the offset height of the userlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
var setHeight = function() {
    _top = -(topbar.outerHeight() - 15);
    topbar.css('top', (stuck ? 0 : _top));
};
```

.outerHeight()

> Description: Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin. Returns an integer (without "px") representation of the value or null if called on an empty set of elements.

.height()

> Note that in modern browsers, the CSS height property does not include padding, border, or margin.